# I would like to count how many times does a string appear in a dictionary, This dictionary has tuple keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The dictionary keys are tuples of two items i.e ('tom', 'tb'): 1 
The count should only count the first item in the tuple. Here is the dictionary below

Dict = {('tom', 'tb'): 1, ('image', 'image'): 1, ('image', 'love'): 2, 
     ('let', 'go'): 1, ('i', 'let'): 1}

For example if i want to count 'image' it should give me value 2 and if i count 'tom' it should give me 1

I am not sure if there is a way to achieve this

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: How would your results change *for counting `'image'`* if I added `('image','image'):1` to the dictionary?

Comment: It will remain 2

Comment: Why doesn't having a 3rd key with `'image'` in it change the count?

Comment: Yes, wouldn't the `'image'` become 3. There are now three occurences of `'image'` in the keys.

Comment: @PYer: Actually now there are *4* occurrences of `'image'`; there are 3 *keys* that have `'image'` in them.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sorry, I miscounted that, I meant to agree with your comment. There are now two tuples with `('image', <another>)` and one tuple with `('image', 'image')`, which totals to 4.

Comment: @Jade So you want to count just the _first_ occurence of a string in each tuple?

Comment: @apena Yes i would like to only count first occurrences

Comment: @Jade please edit your question to reflect your requirement. Also if the tuple keys will only ever contain two items also put that in your question.

Comment: Thanks @apena, I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a vauge question, so I did my best to answer as I interpreted it.

First, I would gather all the keys in the dictionary:

```py
l = {} # replace with your dictionary

key_data = l.keys()
```

Then with this, I would flatten the tuples list, to get a list of all items used:

```
flatten = lambda data: [item for pair in data for item in pair]
key_data = flatten(key_data)
```

Then use the `.count` method: `key_data.count("image")`

This should return the appropriate result. If this does not answer the question, or you have more questions please comment.

EDIT: 
To count only the first item in the tuple, you should change the line to `key_data = [key[0] for key in l.keys()]` rather than `key_data = l.keys()`
You should then not have to include the lines involving the flatten function.

Comment: The answer is close, But i would like to only count the first items in the tuple. e,g Dict = {('tom', 'tb'): 1, ('image', 'image'): 1, ('image', 'love'): 2, ('let', 'go'): 1, ('i', 'let'): 1}     The count for image will be 2 here

Answer (score 0):

Given that you want to count just the first item of each tuple key in `Dict` you can have a function with a loop in it like this:

```
Dict = {('tom', 'tb'): 1, ('image', 'music'): 1, ('image', 'love'): 2, ('let', 'go'): 1, ('i', 'let'): 1}

def GetFirstItemCount (dictData, tupKeyItem):
    count = {tupKeyItem: 0}
    for tupKey in dictData:
        if tupKey[0] in count.keys():
            count[tupKeyItem] += 1
    return count[tupKeyItem]
```

Then call the `GetFirstItemCount` passing it `Dict` and with whatever item you want the count for. You will get 0 if there is no such item in the 'tuple keys' of the dictionary item you pass in.

// outputs 1

```
print(GetFirstItemCount(Dict, 'tom'))
```

// outputs 2

```
print(GetFirstItemCount(Dict, 'image'))
```

// outputs 0

```
print(GetFirstItemCount(Dict, 'foo'))
```